# Where does Umbraco Contour store the forms?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

This is a very simple question really as the title indicates.

I have looked in the database and on the filesystem, but I cannot find where Contour stores  the forms that have been created.

Please note I'm referring specifically to getting the full picture of a form without having to do an export. Where can I "see" Contour's "data source"?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Please note that as I said I am looking for the full picture. I am aware of the UF tables, but not everything is stored in them.

UPDATE: So I know that not everything is stored in the UF tables, because after renaming the method in a custom field type that I've created I get a `System.MissingMethodException` raised saying the method with the old name is missing.

Comment: It's just as @BeaverProj said. All of contour's data is stored within the UF* tables.

Comment: My guess is that it's a caching issue. Have you restarted the app pool? Have you removed the old dll for your custom field type?

Comment: @DouglasLudlow and BeaverProj thank you very much for your help. As it turns out it's advisable to take a step back some times and look an inch to the left... that comment is meant for me btw... explanation at [this thread](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/38488-Back-office-Contour-is-not-loading-following-a-method-rename-in-a-custom-fieldtype). Apologies for wasting your time as well guys! :$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forms are stored in the Umbraco database in the tables that start with "UF"

It uses a key/value structure so it may be a bit hard to pull them out direct.

I recommend using the API to access form data.  More info here:

Umbraco Contour Docs - 
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Developer/

Developer Documentation PDF - 
http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/customer-area/contour-support-and-download/developer-documentation.aspx

Comment: I am aware of the UF tables, but they don't store everything. There has to be another location somewhere that holds form information. If you export a form to XML and look at that, there are things in there that are not in the database. I did specify I'm looking for the full picture.

Comment: What specifically is missing?

Comment: The plug-in is installed on disk to [website]\umbraco\plugins\umbracoContour.  You'll find templates there and the default location where uploaded files are stored.  Or do you mean the actual source code of Contour?

Comment: I've marked as answer, as the answer did indeed lie in the database despite me not spotting it as I was looking in the wrong column (see comment above for link to the our.umbraco thread)... I would have deleted my answer completely had it been possible, but I suppose everyone needs a reminder of their stupidity sometimes :$

Answer (score 5):

Umbraco Forms store it's form structure data in the filesystem, at this location: **\App_Plugins\UmbracoForms\Data\***

You will find form definition in the "forms" directory.

Hope this help.